# How to convert long to wide format for single column with multiple categorical values

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have data that contains a column called "states" with multiple commas separated values as following

```
test <- structure(list(states = c("WA", "SC", "IN", "IN", "WI", "NY",
"CA, CO, CT, DE, FL, GA, IA, ID, IL, IN, LA, MD, MI, MT, NJ, NV, OH, PA, SC, TX, UT, VA, WA", 
"CA, CO, DE, GA, IL, LA, MA, MD, MI, MO, NJ, NV, NY, PA, VA, TX, WA", 
"LA, MS", "DC, MD, VA", "AL, GA, NC", "MN WI", "MN WI", "KS, OK, TX", 
"KS, MO, OK, TX", "IN, MI, NY, OH, PA", "CO, NE", "CO", "CO, NE", 
"AZ, CA, CO, NV, TX, WA", "AZ, CA, NV, TX, UT,WA", "AZ, CA, NV, TX, UT, WA", 
"CA, CT, IL, WA", "AL, AZ, CA, IL, MI, MO, MT, NJ, NM, OH, OK, PA, TX, VA, WI", 
"AL, NC, TX, VA", "IL, MO, NJ, OH", "AZ, CA, CO, MN", "CO, IA, KY, TX", 
"CO, IA, KY, MI, NC, NE, OH, PA, TX", "AR, GA, NC, NM, OK", "AL & WV", 
"KY, MN, ND, OH,OR,PA", "KS", "AL, AR, AZ, CA, CT, DE, FL, GA, HI, IA, IL, IN, KS, KY, LA, MA, MD, MI, MN, MO, MS, NC, NE, NJ, NM, NY, OH, OK, OR, PA, RI, SC, TN, TX, UT, VA, WI", 
"AR, CO, GA, IL, LA, MI, MN, MS, MT, NC, ND, NE, OH, PA, RI, SC, TX, WI", 
"AL, AR, AZ, CA, CT, DE, FL, GA, HI, IA, IL, IN, KS, KY, LA, MA, MD, MI, MN, MO, MS, NC, NE, NJ, NM, NY, OH, OK, OR, PA, RI, SC, TN, TX, UT, VA, WI", 
"AL, AR, AZ, CA, CT, DE, FL, GA, HI, IA, IL, IN, KS, KY, LA, MA, MD, MI, MN, MO, MS, NC, NE, NJ, NM, NY, OH, OK, OR, PA, RI, SC, TN, TX, UT, VA, WI", 
"AL, AZ, FL, KS, MI, MN, MO, NC, OK, WI", "GA, SC", "CA, CO, FL, IL, KY, NJ, OH, TX, VA", 
"AL, AZ, CA, FL, GA, NJ, NM, NV, OH, PA, TX, VA", "ALL 50 STATES", 
"ALL 50 STATES", "ALL 50 STATES", "AL, AZ, FL, GA, MI, NJ, NY, OH, OR, PA, TX, UT"
)), .Names = "states", row.names = c(NA, -45L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                            "tbl", "data.frame"))
test
```

I would like to convert it to a format that has the each "state" as a column and a 1 indicating that states presence and zero otherwise.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This could be what you want. Since you did not provide your expected output, this is my interpretation based on your description. The idea is to add index with `rowid_to_column`, replace "ALL 50 STATES" wiht "ALL", separate the states based on symbols and space with `separate_rows`, and then `spread` the data frame.

```
library(tidyverse)

test2 <- test %>%
  # Create index
  rowid_to_column() %>%
  # Replace ALL 50 STATES with ALL
  mutate(states = replace(states, states %in% "ALL 50 STATES", "ALL")) %>%
  # Separate states with punct and space
  separate_rows(states, sep = "[[:punct:][:space:]]+") %>%
  group_by(rowid) %>%
  mutate(Group_ID = row_number(), Present = 1L) %>%
  spread(states, Present, fill = 0L) %>%
  select(-Group_ID)
```

Comment: There are a few glitchettes in the dataset that need to be considered, too. For example, this solution gives a column for `CO` and `CO` with a space in front, as well as `AL & WV` and `MN WI`.

Comment: @Lyngbakr Thanks. I have updated my post based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

First, I load the libraries.

```
# Load libraries
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(datasets)
```

Next, I replace `ALL 50 STATES` in your dataset with the abbreviations of all 50 states. (`state.abb` comes from the `datasets` package.)

```
# Change "ALL 50 STATES" to state abbreviations
test %<>%
  mutate(states = ifelse(states == "ALL 50 STATES", paste0(state.abb, collapse = ","), states))
```

Finally, I go through each element and parse out the states using `strsplit`, count each state using `table`, bind the results together into a data frame using `bind_rows`, and replace `NA`s with zeros with `replace_na` and `mutate_all`.

```
# Count assuming state only can appear once per row
do.call(bind_rows, lapply(test$states, function(x)table(strsplit(x, "[[:punct:][:space:]]+")))) %>% 
  mutate_all(replace_na, replace = 0)
```

[**N.B.** Your data set is a bit of a mess: most states are separated by commas, but some with only spaces or ampersands. I had use `[[:punct:][:space:]]+` to account for all these possibilities.]

This is a sample of the first 10 rows and first 10 states:

```
#      WA    SC    IN    WI    NY    CA    CO    CT    DE    FL
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# 2     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# 3     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# 4     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# 5     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
# 6     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
# 7     1     1     1     0     0     1     1     1     1     1
# 8     1     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     1     0
# 9     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# 10    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```